# Using Pointers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Whenever Apple creates its own custom classes, it often creates a pointer to the object instead of the actual object itself.

For example, instead of doing:

```
Class object
```

They often do:

```
Class *object = [[Class alloc] init];
```

Why are pointers so commonly used instead of putting the object on the stack? Is there some technical reason for this, because I don't see any immediate benefit of doing so.

EDIT: If Objective-C doesn't support objects on the stack how can they create any non-pointers? I mean I have seen people use NSInteger directly.

Comment: Because it is objective-c not C++

Comment: NSInteger is a typedef for int, i.e. it is a primitive type not an object.

Comment: @UIAdam What about NSRect or similar classes? They aren't typedefs but they are still created directly (i.e. constructor for NSWindow)

Comment: NSRect is a C struct, not an object.

Comment: Allright that answers everything, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support objects on the stack.

Fantastic explanation on Mike Ash's blog [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-15-stack-and-heap-objects-in-objective-c.html)

Comment: Except for blocks, which are technically objective-c objects and are created on the stack when they use local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C regular usage make objects travel all over the place, they can be accessed, modified and managed from a million different places. Stack objects, by definition have only one owner and their life and availability is restricted to the function (thread) that spawned them. This would be a major problem in Obj-C since either the object lifespan would not be controlled, or the object lifespan would be the same as the application (have you seen how much memory those objects take?).

Answer (score 0):

The * (pointer) points to a spot in memory that this object is going to be saved to. Also, This is just the way that objective-c is written. Plus i believe that objective c doesnt allow you to put the object on the stack!

Comment: I think he knows what a pointer is. He's asking why they are used.

Answer (score 0):

if the object is passed around a lot it may be easier to use a pointer than passing a reference. When you know you are passing a pointer it indicates that things might get modified where as a pass by reference may be overlooked and cause things to change when you didn't want them to.

Comment: There's no such thing as references in Objective-C, just as there's no such thing as stack objects.